# How to specify Minimized Mode for BottomAppBar WP8.1

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

Who to set `Mode="Minimized"` in **WP8.1 WINRT** for a `BottomAppBar`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The equivalent of `Mode="Minimized"` for **ApplicationBar** is `ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal"` for **BottomAppBar**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
         ...
        </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 6):

The property is on the Commandbar, ClosedDisplayMode:

```
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```